# Was my query successful?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I perform a variety of actions on my model, eg.

```
User::destroy(Input::get('data'));
```

I need to test whether the above operation was sucessful or not, how would I go about doing it?

I've tried:

```
$deleted = User::destroy(Input::get('data'));

if (is_null($deleted) ) {
    App::abort(404);
}
```

But to no avail.

What is recommended practice here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the [`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`](http://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html)s [`destroy()`](http://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_destroy) method you can see that it returns the number of records deleted.

So the most elegant way to go through it would probably be:

```
$deleted = User::destroy(Input::get('data'));

if ( $deleted === 0 ) {
    App::abort(404);
}
```

However if you don't care about strict comparison you could just go with:

```
if( ! User::destroy(Input::get('data') )
{
    App::abort(404);   
}
```

That works because 0 evaluates to false when not comparing strictly. That's also what the comments on the method say (1058-1060):

> We'll initialize a count here so we will return the total number of deletes
>   for the operation. The developers can then check this number as a boolean
>   type value or get this total count of records deleted for logging, etc.

I would suggest you stick with strong comparison because the return type is just clearer, but you're free to choose whatever you want.

Comment: I stand corrected! I checked the actual model, and yes, it does now return an integer

Comment: Just wanted to comment :) You were refering to an old version of the docs in your first comment.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just do

```
if(User::destroy(Input::get('data')))
{

}
```

This should return true or false if the user has been deleted.

Hope that helps.

Comment: It returns an integer but not true or false. Thanks anyway!