# Did my query insert?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have an additional question regarding a question I previously asked:

[Was my query successful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25244639/was-my-query-successful)

I'm performing an insert query and I wish to know if it was successful or not.

I've tried the following:

```
    $input = Input::all();

    $user = User::firstOrNew(array('email' => $input['email']));
    $user->name = $input['name'];
    $user->username = $input['username'];
    $user->email = $input['email'];
    $user->password = Hash::make($input['password']);

    $user->save();

    if($user){
        var_dump('all good');
    }
    else
    {
        var_dump('fail!');
    }
    die();
```

I modify parts of the above code to make it fail, eg. changing the model name or db fields. But this just causes the code to output a query exception.

How can I check if this query fails, do I need to do a try/catch or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a try/catch block:

```
try
{
    $user->save();
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    // Your code when query fails. 
}
```

When your app is ready for the public, don't forget to open the file `app/config/app.php` and change `debug` from `true` to `false`. This will prevent your app from outputting query exceptions where you don't have try/catch blocks.

Answer (score 0):

`save` returns boolean, so simply:

```
if ($model->save()) // YAY success!
else // unexpected, but no errrors
```

Of course if there's any error, which makes db query or php code fail, then you will see an exception.

The `else` may happen for example when you hook on the `saving` event and stop it:

```
// User model
public static function boot()
{
  static::saving(function ($user) {

    // Not a girl? You shall NOT PASS! ;)
    if ($model->gender != 'female') return false;
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this is pretty much what I had in my question, which fails to work, like you say, I'll get an exception.

Comment: I think there's misconception. Successful code inserts the row or not (according to the business), wrong/faulty code throws exception. You can catch `QueryException` in order to check what happened (like unique index constraint failure etc).

Answer (score 0):

Using Try/Catch may become one best solution.
As example  :

```
public function InsertDummies($data1,$data2,$data3){
        try{
            //your query
            return 'Success to Insert';
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            return 'Failed to Insert';
        }
}
```

Good luck !